# Databricks JDBC driver encoding issues

Tags: jdbc, databricks, dbeaver

I'm using the official Databricks JDBC driver to query data from DBeaver on my Windows machine. However, I am having encoding issues with special characters (Japanese characters). The characters look normal when querying the data directly inside Databricks.

I tried to change the character encoding in the JDBC connection string, but it seems this driver does not support it (no change).

As a workaround, I was able to solve this by starting DBeaver with the following options: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8`. However, we cannot use this as a permanent solution as it affects other connections.

Is there a solution to this problem on the driver level without changing the whole DBeaver application? My theory is that Databricks sends the data `utf-encoded`, but DBeaver decodes it with Windows standard.